# Enumerated list of true-false type questions with underlined space for answers

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem

I would like to write a list of true-false questions:

1. Each question should be numbered.
2. There should be enough underlined space to fill in a single character, i.e. T or F, by hand.
3. Then the question should follow.

The following MWE shows a list which is very close to what I would like

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tfl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tfl]{label*={\alph*.\quad\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Mark the following true or false
  \begin{tfl}
  \item Every dog has a tail
  \item Every animal with a tail is a dog
  \item Every dog has four legs
  \item Every animal which barks and is born with four legs is a dog
  \end{tfl}
\item Compute to the last digit the value of $\pi$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: This is how the MWE looks on my screen]

My primary concern is to push the entire segment of true-false question to the right.

Specifically, I do not want the column marked by the letters a, b, c, and d, to appear to the left of the column marked by the numbers 1 and 2.

Moreover, I would like to know if there is a cleaner way of setting aside a bit of underlined space, than using \hspace in the definition of \setlist.

However, this last bit is a very secondary concern.

---

EDIT 1: I am grateful for all the useful information that I have received. I suspect that @Bernard's answer is the one that solves my problem as I am working within the book class. Regretably, my current LaTex installation will not compile it. I am looking into that issue.

However, using suggestions from @Alan Munn and @Skillmun I have constructed another example which might be of use to others. The critical difference between this example and my original MWE is the individual questions span multiple lines. The use of `leftmargin=2cm' or 'leftmargin=*' ensures that these separate lines are nicely aligned.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tfl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tfl]{label*=\alph*.\quad\underline{\hspace{0.5cm}},leftmargin=2cm}

    \begin{document}

    \section{Exercises}

    \begin{enumerate}
    \item Mark the following true or false
      \begin{tfl}
      \item Every real number is a floating point number.
      \item Every floating point number is a rational number.
      \item Every real number can be accurately represented by a floating point number.
      \item Every real number in the representable range can be accurately represented by a floating point number.
    \item For every real number $x$ in the representable range, there exists a floating point number $\hat{x}$ such that $\hat{x} = x(1+\delta)$, where $|\delta| \leq u$ and $u$ is the unit round off error.
      \end{tfl}
    \item Compute the IEEE single precision representation of $\pi$.
    \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

[image: Improved minimal working example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal example document. The `\hspace` is a pretty normal way to get the underlined space.  See [Long underscore in LaTeX](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/24766) for other options. If you add `align=left` to the list description, does that do what you want?

Comment: `align=left` is an option (like @AlanMunn pointed out), another one could be `leftmargin=2cm`.

Comment: @Skillmon Better would be `leftmargin=*`.

Comment: @AlanMunn you're right. Didn't consider...

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thank you very much for the pointers. The discussion on the long underscore is very informative. `align=left` did indeed do what I want for the MWE. When I tested it for my real example, I discovered that my MWE was too minimal!

Comment: @Skillmon: Thank you very  for your suggestion. `leftmargin=2cm`  solved the problem for my MWE as well as a problem I did not know that I had in my real document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tfl}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tfl]{label*=\alph*.\quad\rule[-0.5ex]{0.5cm}{0.4pt}, wide =0pt, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{enumerate}[wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item Mark the following true or false
  \begin{tfl}
  \item Every dog has a tail
  \item Every animal with a tail is a dog
  \item Every dog has four legs
  \item Every animal which barks and is born with four legs is a dog
  \end{tfl}
\item Compute to the last digit the value of $\pi$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It is exactly what I was hoping for. Unfortunately, I get an error message from pdflatex stating that '! Use of \\tfl doesn't match is definition'. There is a few more lines of error messages which I don't know how to parse or reproduce here, but it is the first `\item` in the true-false list which triggers it. I have pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15.

Comment: Do you  have the error message with this very code?

Comment: Yes. Give me a moment and I will post a link to it.

Comment: Here is a link to a .txt file with the output form pdflatex. http://www8.cs.umu.se/~spock/bernard-error.txt
It continues indefintely, so I had to cut it short. 
It seems to cycle through the same few statements. The link has a complete cycle.

Comment: I can't say much as I don't have the real code you compiled. The definition of the `tfl` environment is just yours, so if you compiled *exactly* the above  code, you should obtain a normal compilation. I don't think that compiling with TeX Live 2015 matters here (albait you should update anyway).

Comment: Bernard: I really appreciate your efforts to help me! I think we might have misunderstood each other. The error message that I linked to was generated when I tried to compile *your* solution. This is why I am confused when you say that you don't have the real code that I compiled. Is there some intermediate code/output that I should upload?

Comment: Not at all. Simply it happens the O.P. copies  the code of an answer into a pre-existing code, and for some reason there's a conflict. I just wondered whether this was the case.  I really don't understand what happens. Unless some invisible characters? Just in case, as the code is rather short, try `re-typing` it in a new file.

Comment: That was a good idea. I typed your example into an empty file, 
www8.cs.umu.se/~spock/bernard2.tex
Sadly, the problem remains. When compiling inside emacs, I get a little more text, than when running from the prompt, see
http://www8.cs.umu.se/~spock/bernard2-error.txt
Please don't sink anymore time into this, as I have a work-around which I have added to my original question. I will talk to my local people and get them to upgraded our tex installation. I will get back you with the result. If I delete the \rule from your example, then it compiles without any problems.

Comment: I found a machine with a newer installation of TeX. The problem associated with \rule evaporated. Thanks again for your time and help.

Comment: I'm glad to see your problem is finally solved. It shows regular updates are really recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`exam`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/exam?lang=en) class in order to achieve what you are looking for (plus a lot more).

---

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{exam}

% \printanswers

\newcommand{\tfq}[1][{}]{%
  \fillin[#1][10.0mm]}

\begin{document}

\section{Exercises}

\begin{questions}
\question [4] Mark the following true or false
  \begin{parts}
    \part \tfq[T] Every dog has a tail.
    \part \tfq[F] Every animal with a tail is a dog.
    \part \tfq[T] Every dog has four legs.
    \part \tfq[F] Every animal which barks and is born with four legs
    is a dog.
  \end{parts}

  \question [6] Compute to the last digit the value of $\pi$.
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

---

The output:

[image]

---

To print the answers, simply uncomment the `% \printanswers` line.

To start other customization, e.g. point position, appearance etc. see the [`exam` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf).

---

**Tips**

To place points in the right hand margin, I find the following very convenient:

```
\usepackage[dvips,pdftex,legalpaper,top=10.0mm,bottom=15.0mm,includeheadfoot,left=20.0mm,right=25.0mm]{geometry}

\pointsinrightmargin
\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{10.0mm}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all this useful information! I l learn more about the exam class for future use. Right now, I really am bound by the book class.

Comment: @CarlChristian You are most welcome. Once you start using the `exam` class, you will find that this is the tool you want to use for all your examinations.